# My App works over WiFi. But not over 3G in android? Any Guesses?

Tags: android, wifi, 3g, xml-parsing

I have developed an App that target version is 4 (Android 1.6) upto 7 (Android 2.1). I tested this app on the dev phone 2 (Google-Io-Device 1.6 version). I am doing some xml parsing stuff through Internet. i set the `<uses-permission>` on my Manifest. it works fine in WI-FI Network. But its not working in the Motorola Droid 2.1 with 3G Network. Is there any more specific stuff to do for 3G network? Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My App works over WiFi Network. But not over 3G Network. Any Guesses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `android.permission.INTERNET`. It's most likely that the server you're connecting to is only accessible from your local network, if it's behind a router/firewall. An easy test is to try to open the same URL you're trying to hit in the system Browser app.

It'd also be helpful to see the traceback from logcat.

Comment: my app is working in wifi. but not in 3g network. can you guess the solution?

Comment: Not unless you do what I said and test the Browser app to that server to check accessibility of that server from a non-local network, and/or post a traceback like I asked.

Comment: @YoniSamlan you are right. but how i can access that server? it works on non-local network, but not on wifi.

Comment: @SaifHamed that's a pretty different question; if you're asking about why your webserver is accessible over mobile internet but not wifi that's a question about your wifi router's configuration or about your server configuration, not about Android, and I'd suggest asking in a new question (maybe on http://serverfault.com/) about that so folks who are experts in that can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @YoniSamlan Thank you for reply.It works fine on my laptop, maybe its router issue. After I waste my day searching, I slept and when I wake up, it works fine on my phone. Thank you, I'll visit servrefault if i face a server issue ;)