# Appmobi application works on Wifi but gives black screen on 3g

Tags: android, networking, wifi, 3g, appmobi

I have a wonderful application made using appMobi, but unfortunately, it is giving up strange problem, where it works absolutely fine on WiFi, but does not work on 3g network. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about appMobi but i would believe it is the way you are connecting the sockets maybe take a look at that or ask appMobi they might be able to help if they set that up for you otherwise check out this link maybe it will be of more service [My App works over WiFi. But not over 3G in android? Any Guesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312065/my-app-works-over-wifi-but-not-over-3g-in-android-any-guesses?rq=1) Good Luck!!

Comment: Sorry I could not be of more help!

Comment: I have already checked the link mentioned, and already posted at AppMobi support, but got no help as of now. Anyways thanks for having a look at my problem Jordan.